# Why isn't anything showing up when I use SELECT * in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I create a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_REP
(
  SRepID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  SRefFName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  SRefLName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  SRepRank VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  IsMentoredBy CHAR(4),
  PRIMARY KEY (SRepID),
  FOREIGN KEY (IsMentoredBy) REFERENCES SALES_REP(SRepID)
);
```

Then I try to insert the following data:

```
INSERT INTO sales_rep VALUES ('SR00', 'Leo', 'Tolstoy', 'First');
INSERT INTO sales_rep VALUES ('SR01', 'Mark', 'Twain', 'Second');
INSERT INTO sales_rep VALUES ('SR02', 'Stephen', 'King', 'Fifth');
```

And when I type this:

```
SELECT * FROM sales_rep;
```

Nothing shows up except for the column names. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Your table has five columns defined.  Your inserts do not list the columns and have only four columns.  Hence, they should be returning an error.

First lesson:  Check for errors!

So, list the columns that are being inserted:

```
INSERT INTO sales_rep (SRepID, SRefFName, SRefLName, SRepRank)
    VALUES ('SR00', 'Leo', 'Tolstoy', 'First');
INSERT INTO sales_rep (SRepID, SRefFName, SRefLName, SRepRank)
    VALUES ('SR01', 'Mark', 'Twain', 'Second');
INSERT INTO sales_rep (SRepID, SRefFName, SRefLName, SRepRank)
    VALUES ('SR02', 'Stephen', 'King', 'Fifth');
```

Second less:  Include the column names in an `INSERT` statement!